# Colab error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: google-colaboratory

While .py files placed in the same folder at Google Colab I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named filename
```

Although the 'filename' file is in the same folder and imported by:

```
from filename import *
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your current working directory actually the same? Use `!pwd` to check.

Comment: I added a code cell to the files and run '!pwd'  and got '/content' in all of them

Comment: Can you share a notebook that shows the issue?

Comment: Please see attached screenshots in the main topic

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your file layout in Drive is distinct from the file layout in Colab.

In order to use Drive files in Colab, you'll need to mount your Drive on the Colab backend using the following snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then, if you have a file like `mylib.py`, you'll want to `%cd /content/drive` in order to change your working directory. Then, you can `import mylib`.

Here's a complete example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12qC2abKAIAlUM_jNAokGlooKY-idbSxi

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the detailed explanation

Comment: @Bob : I usually use the following _code snippet_ for installing some packages and mounting drive: `!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive` , google-drive-ocamlfuse, etc are also installed, more here: [link](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-tensorflow-keras-pytorch.html), but I'm getting the same error. And after this when I execute your command, I get another error `ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module. OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`